# using System.Data.Linq.Binary in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, .net, porting

I want to port some .net Framework code to dotnet core. I don't know how to change this part, since System.Data.Linq.Binary is not part of dotnet core?

```
public interface ICheckConcurrentUpdates : IId
{
    Binary RowVersion
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

do you guys have any idea?

Comment: That's part of LINQ to SQL, which has been deprecated and isn't likely to ever get a Core port. Check if your code uses other stuff from `System.Data.Linq` (like `DataContext`). If so, porting this code to Core may involve rewriting the data layer entirely to use another ORM (like Dapper or Entity Framework). Not a trivial effort.

Comment: I've found Mindbox.Data.Linq to be pretty helpful in the port from .net to core.

Comment: WHAT? They removed linq from CORE? WTH? It's the single greatest datahandler added to .NET.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by using byte [] instead of Binary.